# XSLT copy and sort transform throwing exception in XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, xslt

I have an XSLT transform that is supposed to copy and sort by name - so no content is lost, but the output is sorted alphabetically.
I'm doing this in C# using the `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` method.

Example input:

```
<root>
    <test val="1"/>
    <alpha val="2"/>
    <gamma Order="C">
        <aSubGamma val="3"/>
        <cSubGamma val="4"/>
        <bSubGamma val="5"/>
    </gamma>
    <gamma Order="B">
        <aSubGamma val="6"/>
        <cSubGamma val="7"/>
        <bSubGamma val="8"/>
    </gamma>
    <beta val="9"/>
</root>
```

What I'd like to get in the output:

```
<root>
    <alpha val="2"/>
    <beta val="9"/>
    <gamma Order="B">
        <aSubGamma val="6"/>
        <bSubGamma val="8"/>
        <cSubGamma val="7"/>
    </gamma>
    <gamma Order="C">
        <aSubGamma val="3"/>
        <bSubGamma val="5"/>
        <cSubGamma val="4"/>
    </gamma>
    <test val="1"/>
</root>
```

My XSLT is so far very simple and somewhat right:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I use it on XML where I have **removed** the `Order` attributes on the `gamma` elements, everything is good.
However, with those attributes present I get the following exception:

> Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added.

I've tried many variations on my XSLT but they either produce no output or aren't even valid XSLT!

Is my goal achievable, and if it is what XSLT would achieve my desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't process attributes and child nodes together, so change

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | text() | processing-instruction() | comment()">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note also that XslCompiledTransform is an XSLT 1 processor so using `version="1.0"` on the stylesheet is usually a better idea as otherwise you get forwards compatible processing which might not alert you to the use of unsupported features.